# log4j2 set up issues

Tags: java, log4j2

For some reason my log4j2 won't write anything lower than error on the screen. I have very basic code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TestEN
{
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestEN.class);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.fatal("Test");
        logger.warn("Test");
    }
}
```

This only outputs:

> 16:31:59.883 [main] FATAL TestEN - Test

I don't have a `log4j2.xml` file set up for this project. I'm so confused... Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) about *autoconfiguration*?

Quote:

> 6 . If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging 
>   output to go to the console.

and [`DefaultConfiguration` source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/DefaultConfiguration.java?view=markup) shows default log level being "error"